# Hardware and Monero Mining

Tags: gpu-mining, cpu-mining, solo-mining, mining-hardware, mining-profitability

I was wondering if anyone has built a monster super rig or heard of anyone doing so? I've just been doing research by browsing the Internet and was looking for a motherboard that would hold as many CPU's and GPU's possible. I found this:

http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/C600/X10QBI.cfm

Although, I'm not certain if it would fit the application of mining. It will hold up to 24 cores and has 11 PCI-E slots. I was imagining putting 11 R9 295X2's in it. From what I understand the 11 dual core GPUs would bring around 16.5Kh/s and I'm unsure about the combined 24 cores of the CPUs, but I'm guessing maybe another 1Kh/s? Totaling 17.5Kh/s for a current value of ~2.5BTC a month. I understand that we would be dealing with bleeding edge everything so that would = mucho $$ for considering such a build which = insanity, but I'm just in the mood for speculation and I want to start a real discussion about mining Monero. I simply don't see an in depth thread anywhere that explores many options, so why not start a discussion on the Monero stack exchange? I, occasionally win substantial amounts of BTC gambling and I want to build a computer next time I hit it big. I, not only, want to mine Monero, but possibly other cryptos that may rear their heads. I thought about also adding a significant hard drive to rent out memory on for one of the cloud service cryptos out there, possibly use for some gaming, and anything else that may emerge that piques my interest. So, for me personally, I would like to have a well rounded rig. I hope that there will be people who are very tech savvy that will help me and any others brainstorm on what hardware to use for their Monero mining build. And, yes, what I'm looking to do, primarily, is mine Monero. With both CPU and GPU at the same time. Possibly dedicate some of the hashing power to running a full node. I just want to have options for whatever else may come along. I want to run Ubuntu on Lenux as well which would be a first for me. I have previously only used Windows. The i7 I'm using now doesn't support aes-ni so I can't find any way to mine other than using... ... ... Minergate*cringe* and I get absolute diddly squat. I only have 0.09XMR after five days of mining. I'm sure others are in similar situations. I am inclined to think that it would be more cost efficient to built two separate rigs, each with 8 cores and 6 PCI-E slots, allowing for slightly more GPU power and and 2/3's the CPU power that the above build would have. Probably being more profitable. Please advise... also, feel free to suggest edits or add to this thread with more questions about hardware for mining Monero. Hopefully this will be a nice resource for anyone looking to start mining Monero and crypto in general.

Answer (score 6):

The "24-Core" supported by the motherboard you linked to is *per-CPU*, (e.g., E7-8890 v4 has 24 cores), so per quad-socket motherboard that would be 96 cores. However, these CPUs cost >$7K each yet you won't benefit much from the n-way architecture when mining. Compare that with less than half that price for a 20-Core, 2-way CPU. Those n-way motherboards are very expensive too, you pay a premium for the ability to to have 4 CPUs in the same machine. In addition, if at some point you'll want to use the rig with Windows after all, take into account that for anything above 2-way you must use a Windows Server, another premium-priced component. Bottom line, although you "waste" a core per rig for the miner, several 1 or 2-way rigs will likely yield better mining power per $$$ than a single 4- or 8- way rig.

The above discussion doesn't take into account the cost of hosting, if you intend to host the rigs in a data center then the form factor can have a significant impact on the overall cost.

As for GPU mining, for that you don't need much CPU power, you can use your current machine and just add a strong graphics card. Before you invest in multiple graphics cards make sure the mining software you intend to use can support your configuration.

Comment: My Intel i7 is a 920 @2.67ghz. Not only is it not aesc-ni compatible but I think it may have only two pci-e slots at most, so I will be getting a different cpu and motherboard all together. I was planning on buying just one or two graphics cards initially. I will probably just buy one to begin with just to be safe if I build this myself, probably an r9 295x2, used. I'm just really not sure what motherboard to get? Any sites I can browse that you know of and/ or recommendations for one or two cpu motherboards. Thanks, btw, for the reply. This is really useful info.

Comment: I'm narrowing things down as far as a super monster rig is concerned. For the mb, a rampage v extreme with an i7 6950X cpu. This particular mb is exremely tweaked out and allows for the 7th gen i7's of which the 6950X allows for 40 pcie lanes and the motherboard configures them x16, x16/x16, x16/x8/x8, or x16/x8/x8/x8. The isn't specified but I'm guessing g the fifth pcie slot is there to run five cards at x8 speed. These specs are not intended for mining though, but gaming in crossfire or sli, so I'm thinking it could be advantageous to run five card out of specification...

Comment: From what I'm picking up you don't really want to run at full speed 100% of the time anyways. It's a waste of electricity = waste of $$, and it's hard on your cards. Also I understand that in gaming there may not be much difference when a card is at x16 vs x8. Is this true for mining as well? The bios on this mb are sick ah btw. This YouTube video gives an overview: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=2UHFjWKY6_U. The main mb people report using supports 4th gen Intel CPUs. I'm not sure how many pcie lanes they support but I only see as much as 16. Having forty should increase hashing power right?

Comment: A few suggestions: First define a budget, it will focus you on those configs that are the most relevant. Next, setting aside gaming, make separate decisions regarding CPU and GPU mining, as you can do GPU mining on practically any CPU. Last, select a supplier or vendor that will offer you some comfort level re warranty and see what they offer. I think that having the above in mind will help narrow down your choice.

Comment: My budget is going to be from $2000 to $5000. Somewhere around there seems to be the sweet spot that I end up at when gambling with a little bitcoin. I've won, many times, in that area. I am going to focus on gpu mining. Although, to get the maximum out of my end product I think I'm going to get a mb that houses an i7 that runs 40 pcie lanes. Not the i7 6950x, but the 6850k which is half the price but still has 40 lanes and is an 8 core 16 thread cpu. I will probably build in stages only starting out with one gpu just to get things running and start my build. Then add more gpus as I can afford

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Although at the upper bound of the budget I'd probably split the rig into two machines, each with a cheaper - and more energy efficient - CPU.